# Does setAttribute automatically escape HTML characters?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm investigating a bug in our system where a link's title attribute is being set to something akin to `click if value > 400` but the actual tooltip being displayed is `click if value &gt; 400`. This title value is defined by user input and so the original engineer escaped the text so it wouldn't cause a XSS vulnerability. `click if value > 400` becomes `click if value &gt; 400`.

This extra escaping step seems to cause HTML special characters to be escaped too much so their escaped values are being rendered literally.

To be extra thorough I checked the HTML spec and according to this line it appears that the `setAttribute` function must automatically escape the attribute's value string.

https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-F68F082

*"If an attribute with that name is already present in the element, its value is changed to be that of the value parameter. This value is a simple string; it is not parsed as it is being set. So any markup (such as syntax to be recognized as an entity reference) is treated as literal text, and needs to be appropriately escaped by the implementation when it is written out."*

As I understand it, this line means that the `setAttribute` function should escape HTML special characters. Is that the correct interpretation?

Comment: "by the implementation" i think means the web browser or DOM API, not the client.

Comment: yes, I assumed "implementation" was a fancy catch-all word for the browser / DOM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The plain English interpretation of that quote is that `setAttribute()` does not parse the value as HTML. The reason for that is because you're not writing HTML at all; the value is in plain text, not HTML, so what would normally be special characters in HTML have no special meaning in plain text, and escaping them as though they were HTML would actually be destructive.

`&gt;` is the HTML representation of `>`. You only need to encode it in HTML, not in plain text.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly.

HTML is a data format.

Browsers will parse HTML and generate a DOM from it. It is at this point that character references (like `&gt;`) get converted to the characters they represent (like `>`).

When you use `setAttribute`, you **directly** change the DOM.

This bypasses the HTML data format entirely so the HTML `foo="&amp;"` and the JavaScript `setAttribute("foo", "&")` will give you the same end result.

Comment: but why `<` is not escaped? try `a.setAttribute('a', 'a<s');console.log(a.outerHTML);`

Comment: @VytautasJakutis — You can't start a tag in the middle of an attribute value, so `<` doesn't mean "start a tag" there, so it doesn't need to be escaped.

Comment: try this, see inconsistency in outerHTML: `<div id="a" a="&amp;"></div>
<div id="b" b="&gt;"></div>
<script>
    const attr = (name, escaped) => {
      const div = document.getElementById(name)
      let out = [name, div.getAttribute(name), div.outerHTML, '\n']
      div.setAttribute(name, div.getAttribute(name))
      out += [name, div.getAttribute(name), div.outerHTML, '\n']
      div.setAttribute(name, escaped)
      out += [name, div.getAttribute(name), div.outerHTML, '\n']
      return out
    }
    console.log(attr('a', '&amp;') + attr('b', '&gt;'))
</script>`

Comment: @VytautasJakutis — That throws an exception: https://jsbin.com/bebuzazuwi/1/edit?html,output

Comment: here, fixed https://jsbin.com/mojevidida/edit?html,console,output - look at lines 4&5 versus 1&2 - outerHTML escapes &, but not < - you can actually start a tag in the middle of an attribute.

Comment: @VytautasJakutis — You cannot start a tag in the middle of an attribute value. In the middle of an attribute value `<` doesn't mean "start a tag" is means "a less than symbol". Hence why I said it doesn't need to be escaped. Hence why it isn't escaped in your example. `&` inside an attribute value **does** mean "Start a character reference or entity" so it **does** need to be escaped.

Comment: then why for `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><tag one="<two>"></tag>` xmllint fails with: "a.xml:1: parser error : Unescaped '<' not allowed in attributes values" ?

Comment: @VytautasJakutis — That's not HTML.

Comment: same xmllint failure for `<tag one="<two>"></tag>`, this should be HTML? since that would be the output of .outerHTML

Comment: @VytautasJakutis — Why should it be HTML? There is no `<tag>` element in HTML and you are using XML Lint to test it.

Comment: `<tag one="<two>"></tag>` is the result of .outerHTML, so it should be HTML - `var tag = document.createElement('tag');tag.setAttribute('one', '<two>');console.log(tag.outerHTML)`

Comment: if you want HTML tags, here it is, the same problem: `var div = document.createElement('div');div.setAttribute('data-one', '<two>');console.log(div.outerHTML)`

Comment: @VytautasJakutis — XMLLint does not know or care that you generated the data with a tool designed to generate HTML. It treats it as XML because it is an linter for XML.

Comment: alright, got it, thank you for arguments and confirmation that one cannot use HTML serializer to generate XML :)