# `setAttribute` escaping input?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a bit of trouble correctly understanding whether or not `setAttribute` escapes the input.

Let's assume we have the following invalid HTML:

```html
<iframe srcdoc="<div style=\"margin: 10px\">aA Name</div>"></iframe>
```

This will not do anything in the browser. But as soon as I transform this into HTML and JavaScript via the `setAttribute` method, it works magically:

```html
<iframe></iframe>
```

```js
const iFrame = document.querySelector("iframe")
iFrame.setAttribute("srcdoc", "<div style=\"margin: 10px\">aA Name</div>")
console.log(iFrame.getAttribute("srcdoc"))
```

Two observations here:

1. I get a valid iFrame that shows `aA Name` in the browser
2. The console logs: "<div style=&quot;margin: 10px&quot;>aA Name</div>"

That looks escaped to me (even though `getAttribute could have done that`).

If I try this very same example with the first provided iframe (the invalid iframe HTML code) I get this: `"&lt;div style=\"`

Do I miss something fundamental here?

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50140983/does-setattribute-automatically-escape-html-characters)

Comment: The question is, does it matter? And if so, when? Let's say you put a `x-mydata` attribute on an element. Say, a `div`. Then you run `otherelement.innerHTML=div.getAttribute("x-mydata")`. Does that work?

Comment: @Yarin_007: I checked that and this quote confuses me:
>  is treated as literal text, and needs to be appropriately escaped by the implementation when it is written out.

Basically telling that it doesn't get escaped - even though I can see that it did.

Comment: Well yes, it matters to me for my specific use case. (Implementing that logic in C# - so I have to know whether or not stuff gets escaped)

Comment: Oh. Well in that case I would look in the actual source code of chromium / Firefox, to be sure what's actually happening here.

Comment: Strings inside JavaScript and HTML are escaped/encoded differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not `setAttribute` "escaping" things. There are two things going on:

1. The main thing is that in the HTML, the `srcdoc` attribute ends at the `"` after `style=\`. Backslashes are not escape characters in HTML. If you want to put a `"` in an attribute you're delimiting with `"`, use the named character entity `&quot;`. Attribute text in HTML source code is *HTML*, you need to use character entities in some cases. (Alternatively you could use `'` to delimit the attribute, then use `"` literally.)
2. You're not using the same text in both cases, because of (1) and also because backslashes *are* escape characters in JavaScript string literals.

If you use the same text, by properly encoding character entities in the HTML and only doing necessary escapes in the JavaScript, it works in the HTML and the JavaScript code:

```js
const iFrame = document.getElementById("x");
iFrame.setAttribute("srcdoc", "<div style=\"margin: 10px\">aA Name</div>")

for (const frame of document.querySelectorAll("iframe")) {
    console.log(frame.getAttribute("srcdoc"));
}
```

```html
<iframe srcdoc="<div style=&quot;margin: 10px&quot;>aA Name</div>"></iframe>

<iframe id="x"></iframe>
```

But getting back to `setAttribute`: It doesn't "escape" things, it uses the text you provide as the attribute value on the element object. "Escaping" is a text concept, but when you're using `setAttribute`, you're dealing with the DOM directly, not indirectly via text as you would when specifying the attribute in HTML source code.

Comment: That is a good start. There is still one thing open. If we have the following HTML code:
https://jsfiddle.net/qzx4jn8d/
Shouldn't they have the same output? But they don't.

Comment: @Link - No, because of (1) above. You're still terminating the attribute in the HTML early. Also, the JavaScript version doesn't make much sense, you're putting `"` characters in the attribute value. Look at the live example in the answer for examples of handling both correctly.